# If statement with html id

Tags: php, jquery

I have the code below that gets an `id` if there is any and asks you to click a button to show you data.

```
<input type="text" id="date" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']?>" class="css-input" placeholder="Posting Date..." readonly="readonly" /><br /><br />    
<input type="button" id="validate" value="Let's get to work!" class="btn" />
```

The code below takes you to the data automatically without needing to click a button if there is an id there.:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#validate").click();
});
```

How can I do an `if` statement that if `#validate` is not null then execute the jQuery code else don't. How could I do that whenever I do `<?php if(#date != null)` I get an error, any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean if `#date` has some value? It is quite unclear imho what you are asking!?...

Comment: I want it to be like if #date != NULL then execute the jQuery code, else dont

Comment: Which jQuery code are you talking about? `jQuery("#validate").click();`? And what do you mean by `if #validate is not null`???

Comment: Yes that code, I want it to execute only if #date is null

Comment: So: `if($('#date').val()) jQuery("#validate").click();` but i'm still not sure if by `null` you mean no value (empty string), or string `"null"` or what?!

Comment: An empty value "NULL"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
if($_GET['id'] != NULL){

?>
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function()
 {
 jQuery("#validate").click();
 });
</script>
<?php }?>

</head>
```

Comment: get ID was the id for date @A.Wolff no need to get fussy.

Comment: and i wrote it its null, which is without a value, for it to validate @devpro